# setState for multiple filters

Tags: reactjs, filter, mapping, setstate, splice

So I'm in the process of building out a sidebar which will filter out contents.

My state looks like this.

```
 const [state, setState] = useState({
    Filters: [
      {
        bpm: 0,
        price: 0,
        genreTypeId: 0,
      },
    ],
  });
```

In order for me to filter correctly I need to send my payload to ajax in the same state Filters is in, an array object with each filter being an object and not having more than one value per property.

How do I set up my bpmHandler so that it will first setState if bpm is 0 or null and then for every additional bpm value, it creates another object inside Filters?

I've tried filtering, mapping and splice but I'm still unsure of the logic itself.

Where I'm at currently with bpmHandler

```
const bpmHandler = (e, index) => {
    _logger(e);
    _logger(state.Filters);

    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...state,
      Filters: [
        ...prevState.Filters.splice(0, index),
        {
          ...state.Filters[index],
          bpm: e.target.name,
          price: state.Filters.price,
          genreTypeId: state.Filters.genreTypeId,
        },
        ...state.Filters.splice(index + 1),
      ],
    }));
```

I'm also not opposed to having a bpmList which will just hold all values from bpm filter and then maybe my bpmHandler can map off that into the shape I want but not sure if that's any more effective than just setting state from the jump.

Comment: Just a suggestion: would it make sense to have a separate useState for filters alone? I usually split up the state as far as possible. Makes things simpler.

Comment: And `Filters` is an array, so what is `state.Filters.genreTypeId` yielding?

Comment: And the splice fest you are having might be correct but you could simplify that into something like: `setFilters((prevFilters) => { const newFilters = [...prevFilters]; newFilters[i]=newValue; return newFilters; }`

Comment: Yeah I had another state for holding filter values which would be spliced into the payload shape I need but it felt redundant, I'm open to any methods though

Comment: Just as a personal heuristic I use that hopefully keeps me on the sane side: I structure my component state strictly in a way that allows me the most clear and pain-free component logic. Any other consumer of that data (i.e. some back-end API or some third-party UI control-from-hell) is not so important, and can be fed by transforming the data then and there for their consumption alone. Has served me well so far.

Comment: so would you suggest having a state for filters and another state that will be teh payload sent to api? and just map through the first state into the shape?

Comment: I wouldn't even keep the payload for the request in a state. Just transform the state on the fly exactly when and where you are about to send the request.

Comment: how would you configure setstate to create another object for every value in a property of state?

Comment: If you have a dynamic number of objects to keep in state you need to use an array. There is no way around that. So there would be a `const [filters, setFilters] = useState([]);`